# convolution of positively supported functions in R

Tags: r, integration, convolution, numerical

I want the convolution of two functions defined on `[0,Inf)`, say

```
f=function(x)
    (1+0.5*cos(2*pi*x))*(x>=0)
```

and

```
g=function(x)
    exp(-2*x)*(x>0)
```

Using the integrate function of R I can do this,

```
cfg=function(x)
    integrate(function(y) f(y)*g(x-y),0,x)$value
```

By searching the web, it seems that there are more efficient (and more accurate) ways of doing this (say using `fft()` or `convolve()`). Can anyone with such experiences explain how please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`convolve` or `fft` solutions are to get a discrete result, rather than a function as you have defined in `cfg`.  They can give you the numeric solution to `cfg` on some regular, discrete input.

`fft` is for periodic functions (only) so that is not going to help.  However, `convolve` has a mode of operation called "open", which emulates the operation that is being performed by `cfg`.

Note that with `type="open"`, you must reverse the second sequence (see `?convolve`, "Details").   You also have to only use the first half of the result.  Here is a pictoral example of the result of convolution of `c(2,3,5)` with `c(7,11,13)` as would be performed by `convolve(c(2,3,5), rev(c(7,11,13)), type='open')`:

```
             2  3  5       2  3  5   2  3  5    2  3  5      2  3  5
      13 11  7         13 11  7     13 11  7      13 11  7        13  11  7
 Sum:       14              43         94           94            65
```

Note that evaluation the first three elements is similar to the results of your integration.  The last three would be used for the reverse convolution.

Here is a comparison with your functions.  Your function, vectorized, plotted with

```
y <- seq(0,10,by=.01)
plot(y, Vectorize(cfg)(y), type='l')
```

[image]

And an application of `convolve` plotted with the following code.  Note that there are 100 points per unit interval in `y` so division by `100` is appropriate.

```
plot(y, convolve(f(y), rev(g(y)), type='open')[1:1001]/100, type='l')
```

[image]

These do not quite agree, but the convolution is much faster:

```
max(abs(Vectorize(cfg)(y) - convolve(f(y), rev(g(y)), type='open')[1:1001]/100))
## [1] 0.007474999

benchmark(Vectorize(cfg)(y), convolve(f(y), rev(g(y)), type='open')[1:1001]/100, columns=c('test', 'elapsed', 'relative'))
##                                                   test elapsed relative
## 2 convolve(f(y), rev(g(y)), type = "open")[1:1001]/100   0.056        1
## 1                                    Vectorize(cfg)(y)   5.824      104
```

Comment: This answers my question perfectly, and the pictorial explanation of what convolve (with type='open') does is brilliant. Thanks so much, Matthew!